# How can I override bootstraps sass variables in an Angular 2 project which uses bootstrap-loader?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, sass, webpack

I've tried to include my variables before bootstraps, as many threads suggested, with no luck.

For example, I want to change the width of bootstraps largest screen breakpoint to `1980px`

My `app.component.ts` looks like this:

```
@import './src/app/shared/styles/_variables'; // My own variables
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables';
```

The first file in that list, which is my own file `./src/app/shared/styles/_variables` containing the ovverides look like this:

```
$container-large-desktop: 1980px;
$screen-lg-min: 1980px;
```

But the breakpoints for bootstraps largest screen still remain at 1200px.

I'm using an Angular2 seed project which uses Webpack, and I use bootstrap-loader npm package to load Bootstrap

Comment: Should your own file not be below bootstrap file to override any defaults of bootstrap? I think in your case, bootstrap overrides your own variables.

Comment: Nope. Though I have tried that as well. Bootstrap defines all their variable with !default, which means that those variables will be used UNLESS the variable has been defined previously.

Comment: ok that is fine then I guess, please add this info to your question.

Comment: Are you able to change the variable inside of the bootstrap file? Instead of overwriting it in your own. Or are you worried that it will be overwritten when you update bootstrap?

Comment: Yeah I don't want to hack Bootstraps own file. Then I won't be able to update it, plus it's bad standards and I want to learn to do it the proper way.

Comment: Ok, have you tried adding your own `!default` declaration to your variable. Also sass is cascading, so your file should definitely be below bootstraps file.

Comment: I have tried that but that doesn't work either. Bootstrap defines all their variable with !default, which means that those variables will be used UNLESS the variable has been defined previously. So it SHOULD be defined previous to bootstrap. All threads I've seen online say the same thing and it seem to work for others but all of them load bootstrap with @import statements, and not through Webpack as I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, I'm using bootstrap-loader to load bootstrap, apparently a `.bootstraprc` file is created in the root of my application.

To override bootstraps default variables, I have to add the following in that file: 
`preBootstrapCustomizations: ./src/app/shared/styles/_variables.scss`

From the bootstrap-loader docs:

> **preBootstrapCustomizations**: Customize Bootstrap variables that get imported before the original
>   Bootstrap variables. Thus, derived Bootstrap variables can depend on
>   values from here. See the Bootstrap _variables.scss file for examples
>   of derived Bootstrap variables.